# GAS「指定された ID のアイテムは見つからなかったか、アクセスする権限がありません」というエラーの原因に関する質問

Tags: google-apps-script

GASを使い、自分のgoogle ドライブ内にある指定したフォルダを取得したいのですが、スクリプト実行するたび「指定された ID のアイテムは見つからなかったか、アクセスする権限がありません。」というエラーメッセージが出ます。

なお、アクセス権限を得るためそのフォルダの「共有」設定ページで、GASアカウントのメールアドレスを既に追加済みです。

それでも上記のエラーメッセージが出てしまうのですが、考えられる原因としては何があるかを教えていただけますと幸いです。
初歩的な質問で恐縮ですがお願いいたします。

以下実際のコードです。
フォルダID名には、URLのfolders/以降の文字列を記入しております。

```
function myFunction() {
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('フォルダID名'); //フォルダを取得
  Logger.log(myFolder.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- フォルダIDが間違っている

  - コピペをミスしている
  - 自分がIDだと思っている文字列が実はIDではない
  - IDを保持した変数の値がいつの間にか変わっている
- メールアドレスが間違っている

  - 権限を設定した際に間違ったメールアドレスを追加している
  - GASが、思ったのとは違うアカウントで動作している
- 権限を付与したつもりができていない

  - ブラウザ上で扱っているフォルダとIDで指定しているフォルダが別物である

など、様々な原因が考えられますので、まずは原因切り分けから始められるのが良いかと思います

Comment: ありがとうございます。